# How to run a command line app continuously until instructed to quit

Tags: python, command-line, python-click

I'm using Python and Click to create a simple command line app that takes in a number and adds it to a default number. This is what I have so far:

```
import click
from tqdm import tqdm

init = 5
for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    i + 1

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.option("--n", prompt="Enter number", type=int)
def add(n):
    result = n + init
    click.echo(f"Result: {result}")

def main():
    while True:
        value = click.prompt(
            "Select a command to run",
            type=click.Choice(list(cli.commands.keys()) + ["quit"]),
        )
        if value == "quit":
            break
        try:
            cli.commands[value]()
        except KeyError:
            click.echo("Invalid command. Please try again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note the range counter in line 5 that doesn't do anything - I've added it just so I can ensure that the progress bar happens before the prompt. For the purposes of the question, the range counter is not important, however it is important that the `init` value is set outside of the commands.

This is because I would like the app to initialise the default value for `init` (without user input), and then I would like to re-run the `add` command as many times as I wish before quitting:

**Desired Functionality:**

```
% python bar.py
>>> 100%|█████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:00<00:00, 644286.33it/s]
>>> Select a command to run (add, quit):
add
>>> Enter number:
2
>>> Result: 7
>>> Enter number: 
1
>>> Result: 6
>>> Enter number:
quit
%
```

I can't figure out how to do this. As it stands, my code quits after each `add` input.

**Current Functionality:**

```
% python bar.py
>>> 100%|█████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:00<00:00, 644286.33it/s]
>>> Select a command to run (add, quit):
add
>>> Enter number:
2
>>> Result: 7
%
```

I'm new to Click and command line apps, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If you want the loop to work the "desired behavior" is not what you suggest.

Comment: For the `init` add a `global init` on the `add` method. The error of the loop is a bad behavior of the module, maybe you should check the doc.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to get my desired functionality. The crux of it is defining the functions by themselves, using a class attribute for the `init` value, and using `click.prompt` for the input to `add`, like so:

```
import click
from tqdm import tqdm

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 5

    def add(self):

        while True:
            user_input = click.prompt("Enter number to add (or 'quit')")

            if user_input == "quit":
                break

            try:
                number = int(user_input)
                result = self.i + number
                click.echo(f"Result: {result}")
            except ValueError:
                click.echo("Invalid input.")

@click.command()
def cli():
    f = Foo()
    f.add()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Posting this here in case it's ever of use to anyone.